# Positioning elements with float property

Tags: html, css

Why [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P7w8v/) the `div` is on the same line with the list ?

HTML

```
<ul id="lst">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<div id="id2">Kuku</div>
```

CSS

```
#lst li {
       float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every list item is floated left, and when you float something to the left the next item will end up on its right side.

Basically, the DIV ends up to the right of the list for the same reason the second LI ends up to the right of the first LI.

If you want to separate them, add this between the list and the DIV.

```
<div style="clear: both;">Div</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you apply "float: left" to every single `<li>`, making them "lined up" one after the other from left to right.

Using `#lst {` (instead of `#lst li {`) will make the list appear from top to bottom and the DIV beside it. (If that's not what you want, use CSS `clear` to get rid of the floating.)

Search Google for "css float" to learn more about positioning elements.

Comment: or he could just use `overflow: auto;` on the ul

Answer (score 0):

```
#id2 {
    clear:both;
}
```

Should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you give some styles to the `div`, here is how it looks:

http://jsfiddle.net/9LrUs/

To avoid this, you need to give the `div` a `clear:both`. Here is the example:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="lst">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<div id="id2">Kuku</div>
```

**Style:**

```
#lst li {
       float: left;
}

#id2 {
    clear:both;
}
```